# drop duplicates from a dataframe by a date field in python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

initially i have an empty dataframe with 3 columns

```
name   age     dt
```

my script is

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date,timedelta

Today = dt.datetime.today()
currentdate = Today- timedelta(days=1)
currentdate=dt.datetime.date(currentdate)

df = pd.read_csv("D:/t.csv")  ####the csv has 3 columns and empty
print(df)
df.loc[len(df)] = ['achu',10,currentdate]
print('inserted',df)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
print('dropped',df)
df.to_csv('D:/t.csv',index=False)
```

So in 1st run i am getting something like

```
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: [name, age, dt]
  Index: []
  inserted    name age  dt
  0  achu  10   2015-12-09
  dropped    name age  dt
  0  achu  10  2015-12-09    #looks fine
```

on 2nd run

```
    name  age          dt
 0  achu   10  2015-12-09
 inserted    name  age          dt
          0  achu   10  2015-12-09
          1  achu   10  2015-12-09
 dropped    name  age          dt
         0  achu   10  2015-12-09
         1  achu   10  2015-12-09    #duplicate is still there
```

now 3rd run

```
   name  age          dt
0  achu   10  2015-12-09
1  achu   10  2015-12-09
 inserted    name  age          dt
          0  achu   10  2015-12-09
          1  achu   10  2015-12-09
          2  achu   10  2015-12-09
 dropped    name  age          dt
         0  achu   10  2015-12-09
         2  achu   10  2015-12-09    #Now it is deleting duplicates onwards
```

use cases are

1.if i am changing

```
 df.loc[len(df)] = ['achu',10,currentdate]
```

to

```
 df.loc[len(df)] = ['achu',10,str(currentdate)]
```

it'is working fine and dropping the duplicates from 2nd run as usual.

2.And i checked with drop.duplicates(['dt']),   and drop.duplicates(['other columns']) also. By other columns works fine except dt field

3.my question is, if this is due to datetime.date field i am passing to column dt.....Then my stand will be, why the case datetime unable to start deletion from 1st duplicate, why from 2nd on-wards.

4.In case of converting to str(currentdate) it works fine.The comparision works great and drop duplicate is fine.why such behavior is avoided by datetime(dt field ) in 1st run and followed from 2nd run onwards.

please guide me if i am doing something wrong out there.An example will be a great help.

Comment: When you write and then re-read the csv you don't parse the date column as a datetime so it comes in as `str` dtype, you need to pass to `read_csv` `parse_dates=['dt']` to read the strings as datetime

Comment: @EdChum:then my doubt is from second duplicate entry (also a datetime is getting inserted)  how it is detecting and matching the datetime field(as there also parse_date is absent) and concluding it as a duplicate and deleting.

Comment: @Satya which are you python and pandas versions? Try looking at [this](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11376) now solved bug.